# Building the openfootball database to sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Fellow programmers,

I am trying to create a football pool for my friends and me. Now I would like to automate this process, such that I don't want to enter any match statistics and teams. So I found this excellent repository hosted at this github url:

https://github.com/openfootball/build

As indicated in the examples, you need a directory structure like this for building the actual database:

```
openmundi/               #  -> create folder (e.g. mkdir openmundi)
  world.db               #  -> git clone (see github.com/openmundi)
openfootball/            #  -> create folder
  build                  #  -> git clone
  national-teams         #     ..
  world-cup              #     ..
```

So I have this directory structure in my application:

```
public/tmp/openmundi
   wordl.db # from https://github.com/openmundi/world.db
 public/tmp/openfootball
   build # from https://github.com/openfootball/build.git
   europe-champions-league # from https://github.com/openfootball/europe-champions-league.git
```

Now if I go to my build directory situated in `public/tmp/openfootball/build`, there is a Rakefile which i can run (I only want the Champions League data). So if I do the following in the build directory I'm getting al sorts of errors that the database can't be build:

`rake build DATA=cl201314 # is the command I'm running`

I can see in the following file what the rake task is doing: `public/tmp/openfootball/build/tasks/setups/cl.rake`

The contents of the `cl.rake` are :

```
################################
# football clubs n leagues

task :cl201314  => :importbuiltin do
  SportDb.read_setup( 'setups/teams',    CLUBS_INCLUDE_PATH )
  SportDb.read_setup( 'setups/teams',    AT_INCLUDE_PATH )
  SportDb.read_setup( 'setups/teams',    DE_INCLUDE_PATH )
  SportDb.read_setup( 'setups/teams',    EN_INCLUDE_PATH )
  SportDb.read_setup( 'setups/teams',    ES_INCLUDE_PATH )
  SportDb.read_setup( 'setups/teams',    IT_INCLUDE_PATH )
  SportDb.read_setup( 'setups/2013_14',  EUROPE_CHAMPIONS_LEAGUE_INCLUDE_PATH )
end
```

If I run the above command, the world.db database is building just fine. But when it is trying to import Champions League data into the database, I get the following error:

`deprecated manifest/setup format [SportDb.Reader]; use new plain text format
[info] parsing data 'setups/teams' (../clubs/setups/teams.yml)...
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - ../clubs/setups/teams.yml`

So I guess i needed to have the clubs repository aswell. So if i clone that repository and try to build it again, I got the same error message. And if I look into the clubs repository, it is true that a file called `public/tmp/openfootball/clubs/setups/teams.yml` doesn't exist. The only two that are in that directory are `public/tmp/openfootball/clubs/setups/all.txt` and `public/tmp/openfootball/clubs/setups/clubs.txt`.

Why doesn't it build out of the box? Am I suppose to change the files myself or am I missing crucial parts?

The next part is reading this sqlite file and importing it into my mysql database. But I guess I save that for another post. I would really like to solve this.

If it does make any difference, this is my Ruby version:

`ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for trying football.db  - sorry for the trouble - the club repo got reorganized and two new country repos got added e.g. switzerland and france - the build script will get updated shortly so everything will work as expected out-of-the-box.  You're welcome to post your question to the [opensport/football.db forum](http://groups.google.com/group/opensport) for more detailed answers n insights or check back for updates/news. Cheers.

PS:

> The next part is reading this sqlite file and importing it into my mysql database.

You can import the data into mysql directly (no need to import into sqlite first). Use the "official" build script - see the /build repo and change the database.yml file using the same syntax for the config like Rails (it's ActiveRecord).